# How to bind paper-toggle-button state to its label - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, json, polymer

I currently have several `paper-toggle-button` elements that receive their `checked` state via an `iron-ajax` GET, bringing JSON data of a true/false nature to set the toggles on/off respectively.

I have labels next to the buttons to display their toggled state also, with these taking the same data as the toggles themselves. However, I would like to change this so that the labels are bound to the current state of the toggle rather than the back-end JSON data.

Is this at all possible?

**HTML**

```
<paper-toggle-button id="approver"  checked$="{{current.approver}}">{{current.approver}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="askExpert"  checked$="{{current.askExpert}}">{{current.askExpert}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="autoConnect"  checked$="{{current.Autoconnect}}">null{{current.Autoconnect}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="beExpert"  checked$="{{current.beExpert}}">{{current.beExpert}}</paper-toggle-button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) for `checked` (i.e., `checked$="{{flag}}"`), but `checked` is actually a property, so you should use property binding (i.e., `checked="{{flag}}"`) for proper data-binding notifications. Note the removed `$` from the binding:

```
<paper-toggle-button id="approver"  checked="{{current.approver}}">{{current.approver}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="askExpert"  checked="{{current.askExpert}}">{{current.askExpert}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="autoConnect"  checked="{{current.Autoconnect}}">{{current.Autoconnect}}</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-toggle-button id="beExpert"  checked="{{current.beExpert}}">{{current.beExpert}}</paper-toggle-button>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OjMPZM?editors=1010)

I believe the behavior you're seeking would be achieved simply by fixing the binding type indicated above.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud. This is perfect, and I've only been looking for the answer for weeks! XD